# Do Demons ever pretend to be Gods?

Tags: scripture, gods, darshan, demon

Do Demons ever appear to people on Earth, disguised as Gods, in order to promote immoral and blasphemous behaviors?

Are any events like this described in scripture or literature?

If so, how can we tell the difference between a real God and a demon pretending to be a God?